# Can adjacent thread stacks corrupt each other?

Tags: embedded, rtos

Observation is-
2 threads a and b are created one after the other. Stack size required for thread b is thrice of the allocated stack size. 
Execution of thread b uses/corrupts stack allocated to thread a. Now when thread a executes, OS gives stack overflow error.

Note: New functions are added to thread b. No new function executes in the context of thread a.

RTOS used is embOS.

Is this scenario possible? Or the interpretation of the observations might be wrong in this case? How can I find out?

Comment: Using three times as much stack than you have allocated can basically end up in *any* scenario as this will trigger completely undefined behavior. One of them might be the one you describe. 99.999999% of the others are simple crashes, reeboots, whatever sooner or later. I find your scenario very improbable, but possible.

Comment: how is "IT" detecting (and reporting) a stackoverflow?  and what is "IT"?  have you compiled for stack overflow protection?

Comment: @old_timer, Question updated

Comment: @tofro: I don't know, the given scenario doesn't sound all that implausible to my ears. Thread B wildly over-allocates and trashes far into the contiguously allocated stack region of the next thread. On the subsequent context switch back to thread A the OS notices a trashed stack canary and bails out, and up until that point there is not much to crash unless IPC is performed via stack-allocated buffers passed around directly from thread A.

Comment: @doynax Using 3 times as much stack as allocated is likely to overwrite much more than the other task's stack, assuming it was allocated with a similar size - That was what I was trying to say.

Comment: @tofro: Very likely, say the thread control blocks and stack for thread C would quite naturally be located in the general area for instance. My point is that it seems plausible for none of this to be used until the next context switch after the overrun, at which point the operating system notices the overrun and panics.

Comment: The manual I found online says: "*To detect a stack overflow, the stack is filled with control characters upon its creation, thereby allowing for a check on these characters every time a task is **deactivated**.*'" This implies to me in the case described that the stack overflow should be signalled for task b when task b leaves context. **Not when a enters**

Comment: @tofro Okay. Thanks for the input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scenario is very likely, somewhat depending on the layout of your memory; but almost certainly something bad will happen. embOS normally does no memory protection, since most systems it runs on don't have an MMU to protect you memory.

On most architectures stacks grow downwards, i.e. from the upper memory addresses to the lower ones. If you create your stacks like the following (common to do so when using embOS):

```
static char stack_a[512];
static char stack_b[512];
```

and thread b uses 1536 bytes of stack memory, it will use stack_b for its first 512 bytes, stack_a for the next 512 bytes and 512 bytes from something we can't see here. So bad things will happen...

The reason that embOS detects your stack corruption is (with the configurations I know), that it put some special signature to the lower bytes of the stack and checks at some occasions if this signature is still intact. This although implies, that you need more than 512 bytes of stack space when you want to use 512 byte stack memory in your thread. Having some reserve on your stacks is almost always a good idea.